# jQuery slider click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider

I am trying to create a click event for the pager anchor on my website and I am having trouble with it not doing the event. Can someone help me figure out where I am going wrong.

Here is my jQuery Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.prodSlider').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        timeout: 0,
        pause: 1,
        pager: '.prodPager',

        pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide){
            return '<a href="#">' + slide.alt + '</a>'; 
        }
    });

    $('.prodPager a').on('click', function(){
        setCounter(function(idx, slide){
            return slide.alt;});
    });
</script>
```

Here is the other JavaScript code

```
// Create Global Variable
    var count = 0;
    function setCounter(str){
        if(str.indexOf("Sliding") > -1)
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        else if(str.indexOf("Swinging") > -1)
        {
            count = 9;
        }
        else{
            count = 18;
        }
    }

    function getCounter(){
        return count;   
    }
```

Now all these should be updated when the pager anchor is clicked.

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter())">Overview</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 1)">Features</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 2)">Options</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 3)">Finishes</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 4)">Operators</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 5)">Drawings</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 6)">Installation Instructions</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 7)">CSI Specifications</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onclick="getDesc(getCounter() + 8)">Request a Quote</a></li>
```

This is my sliders id and images.

```
<div class="prodSlider">
                <img src="images.jpg" alt="Sliding"/>       
                <img src="images.jpg" alt="Swinging Low"/>
                <img src="images.jpg" alt="Vertical"/>
            </div>
            <div class="prodPager" onclick="setCounter(This needs to call the function to get the slides alt values)">

            </div>
```

What should happen is when the pager is clicked it will take the slides.alt text and use that to determine the count. When the count is set it should be grabbed by the links to display the apporiate index of the XML objects. I know the XML is correct because when I hardcode the number in there it works correctly so the problem lies in my JavaScript. I feel that I am incorrectly using the `.on('click', function())` and it also may have to do with the scope of my JavaScript variable but I am not sure.

Comment: OK so now I have the Pager class using the onClick="setCounter()" This works when i hard code the setCounter('Vertical') and gets the correct results. Now i need help figuring out a function to obtain the current slide from my sliders alt.

Answer (score 0):

OK the answer what to add this to the .cycle jquery

```
onPagerEvent: function(idx, slide){
            setCounter(slide.alt)   
        },
```

and to get rid of the onclick for the prodPager div

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/manish1706/zhzgmq77/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello");
    $(".js-header-swipe-image").swipe({
        tap: function(event, target) {
            alert('tap');
        },
        swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount){
            //Handling swipe direction.
            alert('swipe');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you could use the `onclick` event vs `.on('click'` - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Thats still not working :( It doesnt throw an error but it doesnt set the value of count.

Comment: Well I got it working if i hardcode the value i want the counter to set it too in the function so the problem is I have to create a function to get the slide that was clicked ons slide.alt value.

Comment: Ouch...thought that might have been the trick. Gonna need someone smarter than me on this. Looks clean to me otherwise, so I'm missing it too unfortunately.

Comment: I found it out its the onPagerEvent: i posted it on my answer if you wanted to see the function it called